# If an item may not exist in a list, can we still do if-else to check condition?

Tags: python

Suppose we have

```
mystr = 'hello.py'
mystr = 'hello'
if not 'py' in mystr.rsplit('.')[1]:
```

The first case is fine, but the second case results in an "out of range" error.

**Goal:**

If .py exists in the string, do nothing. If .py is not part of the filename, do XYZ.
Note : The user input may or may not have a .'extension-type'.

**Attempt:**

Either check the length, or convert the list into a string.

Any alternative? I am not sure if this is too localized. Just wondering.

Thanks.

Comment: What about "foo.py.txt"?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That's a great comment. I simply ignored cases like this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd simply write

```
if not mystr.endswith('.py'):
```

(Assuming, of course, that I've understood your intent.)

Comment: Thanks. Ignacio pulled in a condition I simply ignored. Yet, your solution is still very good. Yes. I would like to find the end type.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you not overlook the criminally underused `partition` and `rpartition` methods. The advantage is that you always get a 3-tuple back, even if the text you're splitting on is not found.

```
partitioned = mystr.rpartition(".")
if partitioned[1] and partitioned[2] == "py":
    # do something
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the posixpath module to find the extension of a file name:

```
>>> import posixpath
>>> posixpath.splitext('hello.py')[1]
'.py'
>>> posixpath.splitext('hello')[1]
''
>>> posixpath.splitext('hello.py.txt')[1]
'.txt'
>>> posixpath.splitext('.ssh')[1]
''
```

Comment: Adding that to my toolbox... nice.

Answer (score 1):

Why not utilize str.rfind?

```
mystr = 'hello.py'
index = mystr.rfind('.py')
if index > 0: #found, do something
else: #not found, do something else
```

Comment: Oh. I always forget these methods. Thanks.

Comment: @CppLearner No problem. I forgot about endswith which is a superior solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just check for it?

```
if '.py' in mystr:
  # do foo
else:
  # do bar
```

But if I am understanding you correctly, this should work better:

```
if '.py' in os.path.splitext(mystr)[0]:
  # do foo
else:
  # do bar
```

`os.path.splitext()` splits the filename into the filename and the extension.

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP is talking about the extension existing in the filename (which is why I answered, your answer encompasses my second thought) or in the actual extension. OP never answered @Ignacio's question.

Comment: Yes. This ideally should work. Unfortunately, the design is so whack that I am just reading a string instead.. But great hack. Definitely going to use this (by the way, I am working on a system level project, so it's useful!) Thanks Blender, very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ".py" in os.path.splitext(mystr)[-1]:
    # do
```

os.path.splitext(mystr)[-1] will grab the "last" element in the list.
In cases where there is only one element it will return that one.

So this will not throw an *OutofRange* exception.
Also, *os.path.splitext()* will always return two objects.